# VueJs-How to complete an asynchronous request before rendering html?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, element, element-ui

I use `el-popover` try to show something, here is the code:

```
<template v-slot:userItem="testData" >
    <template v-if="testData.roleData!=null">
      <el-popover
      v-for ="(item,index) in testData.roleData.split(',')"
      :key="index"
      placement="top-start"
      title="Authority"
      width="200"
      trigger="hover"
      :content="getClaimValue(item.split(':')[0])">
       <el-link  slot="reference" type="primary"  @click="test1(item.split(':')[0])" >{{item.split(':')[1]}}</el-link>
       </el-popover>
    </template>
```

Now the question is that I cannot see the `content` of the `el-popover`.
I guess it is because the method `getClaimValue()` is asynchronous, here is the code:

```
private getClaimValue(roleId:any){
    axios.get(`${env.identityServer}/User/GetClaimByRoleId?roleId=${roleId}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return this.updateTransfer(response.data);
                    
                })
                .catch(
                  (error) => {   
                         Message({
                            message: error.message,
                            type: 'error',
                            duration: 3 * 1000
                          })                  
                  });
  }
```

So what's the problem and how could I see my content of `el-popover` ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try adding a loader till you get response from your async request.

Comment: `how could I see my content of el-popover` - you can't until there is content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get response from axios request directly by return (which I think you can't), you can save response data into another object, for example, `contents`, when the request is finished, the el-popover content will be updated automatically.

in your xxx.vue:

```
 export default class Test extends Vue {

       contents: Object = {};// <--- where to store all contents for el-popovers

       private getClaimValue(roleId:any){
           if(!this.contents[roleId]){
             this.contents[roleId] = "loading";
             axios.get(`${env.identityServer}/User/GetClaimByRoleId?roleId=${roleId}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.contents[roleId] = this.updateTransfer(response.data);
                    
                })
                .catch(
                  (error) => {   
                         Message({
                            message: error.message,
                            type: 'error',
                            duration: 3 * 1000
                          })                  
                  });
             }
           }
          
           return this.contents[roleId];
        }

      
 }
```